# WP_Query for table of contents

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am currently putting this array into my table of contents. To create something like this...

[image: https://youareallslaves.com/live/]

```
<?php
               $args = array(
                   'post_category' => 'live',
                   'post_status' => 'publish',
                   ‘order’ => ‘ASC’,
               );

               $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

               while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                   print the_field('venue');
                   the_excerpt();
               endwhile;

               wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

When I add a new custom post the information is displaying on the same line.
I want each post to start on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = [
    'post_category' => 'live',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
];

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo the_field( 'venue' );
    the_excerpt();
    echo PHP_EOL;
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

In case of HTML

```
<?php
$args = [
    'post_category' => 'live',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
];

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<div class="list">
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="list-item">
            <?php echo the_field( 'venue' ); ?>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: The second one worked, is it possible to make the loop appear in each new row? With the <br> tag I am finding it hard to style the table of contents.

Comment: @Helena i will ajust my answer

Comment: @Helena i ajusted my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use tag div for record in 1 one.

```
<?php
$args = [
    'post_category' => 'live',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'order'         => 'ASC',
];

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

$count = 1;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo "<div class='item item-".$count."'>";
    echo the_field( 'venue' );
    the_excerpt();
    echo "</div>";
    $count++;
endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```